# What is TS component in this PCB?

Tags: charger, usb-pd

I am drawing a USB type-C PD charger based on the information given by this [manufacturer](https://en.hynetek.com/2421.html), but I have doubt related to the components (TS4, TS3, TS7, TS8, TS6, TS5) in the PCB board, what are those components?, in the [datasheet](https://www.hynetek.com/uploadfiles/site/219/news/d45ab9c8-5dd6-46d5-8572-95e337dd3467.pdf) page 11, they shows the schematic of that board but it does not seem to appear the TS components. Thank you
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are test points, onto which an oscilloscope probe may be easily clipped.

The full set of test points is listed in the upper-left of the schematic; it appears that some of them are the ones you highlighted, while others are simple through-holes or headers (along the bottom edge of the PCB, and VBATT just above).

The test points that have a scope-friendly clip are the ones that might be more commonly probed by a user of the board.

I can't tell what exact test point that is from the photo alone. Chances are, they include it on the bill of materials and placement list sent to their assembler, but they happened to not include it in the schematic that is in your question. An *example* of such a test point would be [this product](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/keystone-electronics/5002/255328).

Comment: is there a component or part to include those as footprint and component for assembly? or which one is the connector used?

Comment: @imt_blake Not sure of the exact connector model from the photo; added a remark to the answer to address this.

Comment: The PCB footprint would just be a single pad with a suitable size plated through hole.  The PCB symbol could be a small circle with a single pin, as in the box at the top left of the schematic.

Comment: If you do any amount of electronic design and PCB layout, you will have to make some of your own schematic symbols and PCB footprints.  ECAD programs include the necessary editors to do that.  I've found that it is often faster to make my own symbols and footprints than to search for something suitable in the provided libraries or elsewhere.